How can I use Utilities API with 2 properties?
In my use case, I have 3 paragraph styles with the following settings:
P1 - font-size: 20px, line-height: 22px P2 - font-size: 18px, line-height: 20px P3 - font-size: 16px, line-height: 18px
I would like to use the utilities API along with the responsive feature as the paragraphs change according to the breakpoints.
I'm wondering how can I create a prg-1, prg-2, etc
I tried the following
$paragraphs_fs: (
  1: 20px,
  2: 18px,
  3: 16px,
);

$paragraphs_lh: (
  1: 1.75rem,
  2: 1.625rem,
  3: 1.5rem,
);
    'paragraphs': (
      property: font-size line-height,
      class: 'prg',
      responsive: true,
      values: map-merge($paragraphs_fs, $paragraphs_lh),
    ),

However, the result is:
.prg-1 {
  font-size: 1.75rem !important;
  line-height: 1.75rem !important;
}

.prg-2 {
  font-size: 1.625rem !important;
  line-height: 1.625rem !important;
}

.prg-3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
  line-height: 1.5rem !important;
}

I would like to use the utilities API along with the responsive feature as the paragraphs change according to the breakpoints.
